# Using a loop for multiple buttons in Protractor

Tags: javascript, webdriver, protractor

Currently I am working on a Protractor project that has multiple or just one, recurring, non-problematic, error messages that must be cleared (clicked OK) before continuing with the rest of the tests.  The error messages, which show at the beginning of the page load, can at times be more numerous than one, and I wish to "click out" of all of them.  The code for one was simple:

```
alertMessages['alertMessage'].isPresent().then(function (isHere) {
                        if (!isHere) {
                           alertMessages['alertMessageOKButton'].click();
                        }
                    });
```

I attempted a simple loop around it which, for some reason beyond my knowledge, worked for a time and has now ceased to work appropriately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you would like to test an alert boxes. If I am right, use `browser.switchTo().alert().accept();`

For more information please visit this link: 
https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/3d60689b423749686973227f4b26cbb494f60b66/spec/basic/navigation_spec.js#L8

And see browse for more information in here: https://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=webdriver.WebDriver.TargetLocator.prototype.alert

Comment: Thanks for responding but I can click any one alert just fine, it is that after I click one, another appears blocking the flow of the application.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [async.whilst](https://github.com/caolan/async#whilsttest-fn-callback). Basically keep on clicking until all alerts are dismissed. This is somewhat modification of your code (btw I don't know what `alertMessages` is). But I hope you get the idea.

```
async.whilst(
    function () { 
        return alertMessages['alertMessage'].isPresent().then(function(isPresent){
            return isPresent;
    }) },
    function (callback) {
      alertMessages['alertMessageOKButton'].click();
    },
    function (err, n) {
      console.log('Total number of alerts were '+ n);
      if(err) {
         done(err);
      } else {
        done();
      }
    }
);
```